# Spring @transactional with unit tests giving failure

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit

I am newbie with hibernate+spring setup.

I am strictly using annotations and trying to write a simple test.

Here is the configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ret = new BasicDataSource();
        ret.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ret.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb");
        ret.setUsername("root");
        ret.setPassword("root");
        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    SessionFactory sessionFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(
                dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.mypackages.domain");
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory lsfb) {
        HibernateTransactionManager mgr = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        mgr.setSessionFactory(lsfb);
        return mgr;
    }
}
```

My Junit test case is annotated with @transactional.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={DatabaseConfiguration.class})

public class TestMyDao extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests  {

    @Autowired
    MyDao dao; 

   @Autowired
   SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testCreate() {
        DomainObj obj = new DomainObj();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(obj);
    }
}
```

This piece of code fails as there is no session attached to the current thread.

Isn't `@Transactional` suppose to take care of it? If not how to use `@Transactional` and get access to the session?

Error

```
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@6bf256fa] to process 'after' execution for test: method [public void com.mytest.testCreate()], instance [com.mydao.TestDao@2227a6c1], exception 
[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@15fa55a6] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@4a7761b1] bound to thread [main]] 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@4a7761b1] bound to thread [main]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(HibernateTransactionManager.java:635)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:883)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:830)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:218)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Only adding `@Transactional` isn't enough you will also need to instruct your test that they need to run under a transaction. Either by extending the `AbstractTransactionalJUnitSpringContextTests` or by including the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` as a listener in the `ContextConfiguration`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am now extending the test class from 'AbstractTransactionalJUnitSpringContextTests' and still facing the same error. I have included the error in the post now.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Add your testcase and not only the method.

Comment: It isn't so much your test that fails its the `@After` method, so not sure what you are doing in that method...

Comment: @M.Deinum Added the surrounding code. I have not written any @ After method.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have debugged and verified that following line throws the exception

`  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`

Comment: Where is your sessionFactory coming from? You only have a dao?

Comment: Sorry. Copy paste error! @M.Deinum

Comment: The weird thing is it fails after running your test when cleaning up the resources... Weird. You have the correct hibernate versions for the configuration? And use all the correct spring jars.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103099/discussion-between-s-v-and-m-deinum).